# Inserting character at a specific position

Tags: c++, arrays, string, insert

So I have to write a program that adds a character in array at specific position taking input from user. E.G, the array is {‘A’,‘B’,‘R’,‘L’,‘O’,‘M’,‘C’}, so after inserting "M" at index 2, it should become {‘A’,‘B’,‘M’,‘R’,‘L’,‘O’,‘M’,‘C’}. My problem is that my code overwrites the value at index 2 hence losing it in the process..

Here's the code:

```
    char array[20], insert, temp;
    int size = 10, index, count = 0;
    cout << "Enter characters : ";
    cin >> array;
    cout << "Enter a character you want to insert : ";
    cin >> insert;
    cout << "Enter index you want to insert in : ";
    cin >> index;
    for (int i = index; array[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
      temp = array[index + 1];
      array[index] = insert;
    }

    for (int i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
```

Comment: Ok, so if you look at what you've written down, `'R'` in position 2 ends up in position 3, and all the letters get shifted over by one forward. Can you point to which specific line in your code does that? That's a trick question. There's no such line. That's your problem.

Comment: You would have to save temp at array[index+1]. But an fixed size array isn't a good data structure for your task.

Comment: can you use `std::string` ? `std::string::insert` already does what you want

Comment: You shouldn't use C-strings. But more important you shouldn't use C-strings with std::cin because you can't limit the number of characters and your program can cause a buffer overflow.

Comment: Alright so as pointed by @RoQuOTriX, I edited the code so that it saves the value present at next index and then puts the value of insert at given index,, yet it still overwrites the value at index 2

Comment: @scypx that is not what i meant... I meant `array[index + 1] = temp` after you read the last temp value

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use C-strings. But more important you shouldn't use C-strings with std::cin because you can't limit the number of characters and your program can cause a buffer overflow.

You should use a dynamic container like [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Most containers provide a method like [std::string::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) to insert elements at a specific position.

Know your tools (algorithms) and don't reinvent the wheel.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::size_t;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter characters : ";
    string array;
    cin >> array;
    cout << "Enter a character you want to insert : ";
    string insert;
    cin >> insert;
    cout << "Enter index you want to insert in : ";
    size_t index;
    cin >> index;
    array.insert(index, insert);
    for (const auto &c : array) {
        cout << c << " ";
    }
}
```